# There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties

Tags: apache-calcite

I would like to use calcite volcano planner to optimise a query. It doesn't work and return me the exception:

**There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties: convention=NONE, sort=[]. All the inputs have relevant nodes, however the cost is still infinite.
Root: rel#18:RelSubset#4.NONE.[]**

**Original rel:**

**LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $3)], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 81495.22499999999, cumulative cost = {686245.725 rows, 61452.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 4**

**LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 543301.5, cumulative cost = {604750.5 rows, 61451.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 2**

***LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]]): rowcount = 59.0, cumulative cost = {59.0 rows, 60.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 0***

***LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]]): rowcount = 61390.0, cumulative cost = {61390.0 rows, 61391.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 1***

***LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]]): rowcount = 1.0, cumulative cost = {0.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 3***

This the code causing the issue:

```
val rootSchema = CalciteSchema.createRootSchema(true).plus
val schema = rootSchema.add("CALCITE_TEST", new AbstractSchema())
schema.add("TTLA_ONE", TableA())
schema.add("EMPTY_T", TableS())
schema.add("TTLR_ONE", TableR())
val config = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder.defaultSchema(schema).build
val builder = RelBuilder.create(config)

val opTree: RelNode = builder
  .scan("TTLA_ONE")
  .scan("TTLR_ONE")
  .join(JoinRelType.INNER, "X")
  .scan("EMPTY_T")
  .join(JoinRelType.INNER, "X")
  .build()

val rw = new RelWriterImpl(new PrintWriter(System.out, true))

opTree.explain(rw)
println()
val program = HepProgram.builder
  .addRuleInstance(FilterJoinRule.FILTER_ON_JOIN).build

val hepPlanner = new HepPlanner(program)
hepPlanner.setRoot(opTree)
hepPlanner.findBestExp.explain(rw)

println()

val cluster = opTree.getCluster
val planner = cluster.getPlanner().asInstanceOf[VolcanoPlanner]
planner.setRoot(opTree)

// add rules
planner.addRule(PruneEmptyRules.PROJECT_INSTANCE)
//     add ConverterRule
planner.addRule(EnumerableRules.ENUMERABLE_MERGE_JOIN_RULE)
planner.addRule(EnumerableRules.ENUMERABLE_SORT_RULE)
planner.addRule(EnumerableRules.ENUMERABLE_VALUES_RULE)
planner.addRule(EnumerableRules.ENUMERABLE_PROJECT_RULE)
planner.addRule(EnumerableRules.ENUMERABLE_FILTER_RULE)
planner.addRule(Bindables.BINDABLE_TABLE_SCAN_RULE)
val optimized = planner.findBestExp

optimized.explain(rw)
```

It produces the output belove:

```
4:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $3)], joinType=[inner])
  2:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
    0:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]])
    1:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]])
  3:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]])

10:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $3)], joinType=[inner])
  7:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
    0:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]])
    1:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]])
  3:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]])


There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties: convention=NONE, sort=[]. All the inputs have relevant nodes, however the cost is still infinite.
Root: rel#18:RelSubset#4.NONE.[]
```

I added some rules on the VolcanoPlanner, what can be the issue?

Comment: It seems that the `HepPlanner` use in your example is unneeded for the query you're trying to process. Where do the tables come from? What is their convention?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The tables are defined in [here](https://github.com/srapisarda/stypes-calcite/tree/master/src/test/scala/uk/ac/bbk/dcs/stypes/calcite/schema).
The test using them is in [here](https://github.com/srapisarda/stypes-calcite/blob/master/src/test/scala/uk/ac/bbk/dcs/stypes/calcite/CalciteSlideTest.scala#L249)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changed

```
val cluster = opTree.getCluster
val planner = cluster.getPlanner().asInstanceOf[VolcanoPlanner]
planner.setRoot(opTree)
```

to

```
val cluster = opTree.getCluster
val desiredTraits = cluster.traitSet.replace(EnumerableConvention.INSTANCE)
val planner = cluster.getPlanner.asInstanceOf[VolcanoPlanner]
val newRoot = planner.changeTraits(opTree, desiredTraits)
planner.setRoot(newRoot)
```

by introducing

```
val desiredTraits = cluster.traitSet.replace(EnumerableConvention.INSTANCE)
```

and creating a new root form the desiredTraits

```
val newRoot = planner.changeTraits(opTree, desiredTraits)
```

I also added some projections to the query, but that is not necessary for Volcano running well.

This is now the output:

```
6:LogicalProject(X=[$0], X0=[$2])
  5:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $2)], joinType=[inner])
    3:LogicalProject(X=[$0], X0=[$1])
      2:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
        0:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]])
        1:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]])
    4:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]])

16:LogicalProject(X=[$0], X0=[$2])
  14:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $2)], joinType=[inner])
    11:LogicalProject(X=[$0], X0=[$1])
      9:LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
        0:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]])
        1:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]])
    4:LogicalTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]])

103:EnumerableProject(X=[$2], X0=[$0])
  102:EnumerableHashJoin(condition=[=($0, $2)], joinType=[inner])
    52:EnumerableTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, EMPTY_T]])
    101:EnumerableProject(X=[$0], X0=[$1])
      100:EnumerableMergeJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
        33:EnumerableTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLA_ONE]])
        37:EnumerableTableScan(table=[[CALCITE_TEST, TTLR_ONE]])
```